# Bash For loop logic in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, bash, for-loop

I am looking for something similar to the bash for loop in oracle

```
for i in 1 5 3 8; do echo "print $i"; done
```

so this would result as

```
print 1
print 5
print 3
print 8
```

I want something similar logic in Oracle SQL like

```
for i in 1 5 3 8; do echo " select * from TABLE where column1='$i';"; done
```

so this would result as

```
select * from TABLE where column1='1';
select * from TABLE where column1='5';
select * from TABLE where column1='3';
select * from TABLE where column1='8';
```

So how do I get something similar logic in Oracle SQL

Comment: Are you looking for SQL or PL/SQL?  SQL does not have loops.  Potentially, you just want `where column1 in (1,5,3,8)`.  But it really depends on what you are trying to accomplish-- one SQL statement can't run 4 separate queries.  It could run one query that has all four sets of results.

Answer (score 0):

I hope that I understood your request correctly:

```
SELECT r FROM (
        SELECT ROWNUM r
          FROM DUAL
    CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= 8)
 WHERE r IN (1, 5, 3, 8)
```

Basically, we're creating a column of all numbers from 1 through 8 and then selecting the ones you requested. If you're going to work with strings or with a large range of numbers (but a small amount of rows), this solution won't be very efficient, and then you should store your values in a table.

Answer (score 0):

You can build a loop in plsql, for example:

```
begin
    for i in (
                select 1 as num from dual union all
                select 5 from dual union all
                select 3 from dual union all
                select 8 from dual
             )
    loop
        dbms_output.put_line('number: ' || i.num);
       /* do whatever you need */ 
    end loop;
end;
/
```

If you need this to run a query, maybe you can simply use the `IN`:

```
select *
from table
where column1 in (1, 5, 3, 8)
```

or, to  build a more complex list:

```
select *
from table
where column1 in (
                  select something
                  from ...
                 )
```